# Reshape panel data from wide to long

Tags: r

My data frame looks like this:

```
person. id98 id100 id102 educ98 educ100 educ102 pid98 pid100 pid102
  1.     3.   0.    0.    2.     4.       5.    T.     F.     F
  2.     ....
```

I hope to transform it like this:

```
person.  year.   id.     educ.  pid. 
  1.      98
  1.     100
  1.     102
```

In Stata, I know that the "reshape" command can automatically identify the year from those variables' names. In R, I don't know how to deal with that.
I want to get the number that is trailing in each column name and bundle the column based on that number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`. Using data from  @ThomasIsCoding

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, 
                    cols = -person., 
                    names_to = c('.value', 'year'), 
                    names_pattern = '([a-z]+)(\\d+)')

#  person. year     id  educ pid  
#    <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
#1       1 98        3     2 TRUE 
#2       1 100       0     4 FALSE
#3       1 102       0     5 FALSE
```

Comment: It works! But the year value is "character", not "numeric" or "integer". I tried as.numeric and as.integer to fix it, but they did not work. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: @tobinz Add `%>% mutate(year = as.integer(year))` after `pivot_longer`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I also tried `names_ptypes(list(year = integer()))`  in the function, doesn't work. Don't know why

Comment: I will. My reputation is quite low now which does not allow me to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use `reshape`, maybe the code below could help

```
reshape(
  setNames(df, gsub("(\\d+)", "\\.\\1", names(df))),
             # the gsub needed because `reshape` expects a period as a separator
  direction = "long",
  varying = -1
)
```

which gives

```
      person. time id educ   pid
1.98        1   98  1    2  TRUE
1.100       1  100  1    4 FALSE
1.102       1  102  1    5 FALSE
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(person. = 1, id98 = 3, id100 = 0, id102 = 0, educ98 = 2, 
    educ100 = 4, educ102 = 5, pid98 = TRUE, pid100 = FALSE, pid102 = FALSE), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-1L))
```

Comment: `reshape` can handle this out of the box without renaming too if you specify the separator - `reshape(df, idvar="person.", varying=-1, direction="long", sep="")` . Because you haven't specified `idvar=` too, you're getting what looks to be an incorrect result for the output `id` column.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `data.table` package this is fairly easy.
As a note I think this'll only work if the columns are ordered in the same order i.e id90 id100 id102 pid90 pid100 pid102 ... etc.

## Edit

The aforementioned issue has been solved in this new code.

```
# loading data.table
if(!require(data.table)){
    install.packages("data.table")
    library(data.table)
}
df= data.frame(person=1:5, id90=rnorm(5), id91=rnorm(5), id92=rnorm(5),  pid90=rnorm(5), pid91=rnorm(5), pid92=rnorm(5),  educ90=rnorm(5), educ91=rnorm(5), educ92=rnorm(5))
# turn data.frame in data.table
setDT(df)
cols = colnames(df)[order(colnames)]

# df[, ..cols] reorders the columns alphabetically 
# to evade the problem stated above.
# id.vars is the id vars
# using patterns with measure vars will bundle all the columns 
# that match the regex pattern in the same column 
dt <- melt(df[, ..cols], id.vars="person", measure.vars=patterns(id="^id", educ="^educ", pid="^pid"))

# getting the years
years = gsub('^id', '', colnames(df)[grepl('^id', colnames(df))])

# changing the years
dt[, c("year","variable"):=list(years[variable], NULL)]
```